# Yii2 Gridview afterRow function

Tags: gridview, yii2

Yii2 Gridview's afterRow calls an anonymous function after each data model. Is there a way the do an anonymous function only after the last data model? I want to add blank rows and the end.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'id' => 'table',
    'tableOptions' =>[
        'class'=>'table table-condensed table-bordered'
    ],
    'afterRow' => function($model, $key, $index) {
        return Html::tag('tr',
            Html::tag('td', Html::textInput($name))
            .Html::tag('td', Html::textInput($name))
        );
    },
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `renderTableBody()` in GridView class does not allow such functionality.
You can try to override this method or check in your afterRow anonymous function if it is last index.

I think second option is better.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'showFooter' => true,

> example:

```
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute' => 'id',
                'footerOptions' => ['colspan' => '2'],
                'footer' => 'data footer',  // or anonymous function
            ],

            [
                'attribute' => 'text',
                'footerOptions' => ['style' => 'display:none;'],
            ],
        ],
]); ?>
```

---

```
'showFooter'=>true,
'footerRowOptions'=>['style'=>'property1:style, property2:style, ...],
```